# Objective-C IF statement with multiple OR statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do multiple OR statements as part of a singe IF statement.

Currently I am doing them like this:

```
            if ((i == 1) || (i == 4) || (i == 7)) {}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, the two current answers are less clear. Kent Beck: "“Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work” - Kent Beck"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `switch` block with fall through.

```
switch (i)
{
    case 1:
    case 4:
    case 7:
        yourCode;
        break;
}
```

Comment: But this is not the same like OR, it's more like using several else if conditions for the same case

Comment: Actually it is, because `switch` doesn't stop when it reaches a valid condition (unless you use `break`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSArray`'s `containsObject:` method, like this:

```
if ([@[@1, @4, @7] containsObject:@(i)]) {
    ...
}
```

The usefulness of this approach improves with the length of the list: with three items, your solution looks better, but once you cross the limit of about ten numbers, this solution becomes more and more readable:

```
if ([@[@1, @3, @12, @17, @23, @27, @31, @41, @43, @57] containsObject:@(i)]) {
    ...
}
```

You can make a named array for the list of expected constants `@[@1, @4, @7]` to shorten the `if`, like this:

```
NSArray *expect = @[@1, @4, @7];
...
if ([expect containsObject:@(i)]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: But you lost quite a few cycles of cpu if you look it up in arm assembly code, I believe.

Comment: You can use the new `@(i)` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]`.

Comment: @Lefteris Unless this is in a really tight loop, a few hundred cycles here and there makes zero difference these days: after all, we're talking CPUs with clock cycles in gigahertz.

Comment: But it is a less clear solution that the OP presented. Don't do this!